# form serialization issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I have defined a ViewModel like:

```
public class TestModel : Test
    {        
        public TestModel (Models.Test1 t1)
            :base(t1)
        {  }
        public TestModel (Models.Test1 t1, Models.Test1 t2)
            :base(t1,t2)
        {    }
```

Class Test is defined as:

```
public class Test
    {
        public Test(Models.Test1 t1)
        {
//set the properties for t1
}

public Test(Models.Test1 t1, Models.Test1 t2)
            :this(t1)
{
//set properties for t2
}

}
// properties for t1 and t2
}
```

TestModel is used in my View to display combined fields from t1 and t2. When I submit the form like this:

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {                 
            Save($(this).serialize(),
             function () {
                 $('.loading').show();
             },
             function () {
                 alert('success');
             });
         });
         $('a.save').click(function (evt) {                
             $(this).parents('form').submit();
         });



- the controller action below is never hit.

    [HttpPost]        
             public JsonResult Save(TestModel camp)
            {                           
                    Helper.Save(camp);
                    return Json(JsonEnvelope.Success());           
            }
```

I think the serialization is not working because TestModel derives from Test. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the serialization is not working because TestModel derives
>   from Test. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

The serialization doesn't work because your `TestModel` doesn't have a parameterless constructor. The default model binder doesn't know how to instantiate this class. Only classes with parameterless constructors should be used as view models. Or you will have to write a custom model binder to indicate which of the 2 custom constructors to use.

So go ahead and rethink your design of view models. It's OK to use inheritance but no custom constructors.